# Проблемы с веткой разработки в GIT

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch, git-push

День добрый! Учусь использовать git, работать с ветками. Возникла проблема. У меня есть основной домен (допустим, mydomen.com) и поддомен dev.mydomen.com. На основном домене, по сути, то, что в ветке master, а в поддомене dev может находится что угодно (состояние той ветки, с которой я в данный момент работаю. Проблема в том, что к основному домену привязан SSL сертификат, и работа с API внешних сервисов идет по одному принципу, взаимодействие идет не с настоящей базой, а тестовой и т.д. Приходится каждый раз менять файлы, строчки, свои конфиги. При слиянии вообще ад. Как поступить? По сути есть 3 файла, содержимое которых меняется в зависимости от того, с доменом или поддоменом я сейчас работаю.
Как научить гит понимать это? Или я как-то не правильно мыслю?

Comment: Это должно быть не в гите, а в грамотной организации конфигурации вашего сайта. Погуглите, как это сделано, например, в Ruby on Rails - имхо, образец для подражания. Кстати, пароли, api-ключи и прочие секретные вещи пихать в гит вообще нельзя.

Comment: Как насчёт того чтобы использовать систему управления конфигурацией вроде ansible? Тогда в зависимости от конфигурируемого хоста у вас будут разные конфиги получаться. Что касается секретов — верно выше пишут, их нельзя хранить под гитом (либо хранить, но зашифрованными)